# How to remove trailing zeros after decimal in Azure Data Flows/Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I pulling couple of columns from source using data flows, i want to remove the trailing zero after decimal in Azure Data Flows/Data Factory

```
Height    weight
23.4200   23.4020
1.4000    232.2200
2.00      2.0010
```

Required Output:

```
Height    weight
23.42     23.402
1.4000    232.22
2         2.001
```

could you please anybody help me how can i achieve the required result.
I tried using toFloat() in derived column transformation.

Please help

Comment: Have you tried `toFloat(Height,'###.##')`?

Comment: i tried toFloat({Height (cm)},'###.##'). It throws error for me 'Job aborted due to stage failure:'

Comment: So 'Height (cm)' is your column name? How about `toFloat(byName('Height(cm)'),'###.##')`?

Comment: Yes its my column name.And same error repeated.

Comment: This syntax for column names with spaces and special chars is correct: toFloat({Height (cm)},'###.##'). Is this a Derived Column transform? When you click on Data Preview, are you able to see the preview data?

Comment: HI Mark, yes i am using derived column transformation. In the data preview i have observed the error 'Job aborted due to stage failure:'

Answer (score 0):

I have done this with rtrim function in expression builder.
Now, that function works only with strings, so one more step for this is to convert you float or decimal type toString.
Mine expression looks like this: rtrim(toString(NUMVALUE),'0')